# EF does not include where clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a small issue with EF. I'm performing a query on a large table, and it takes very long. I think I found the cause, but cannot find a solution;

My LINQ query looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> o = (from P in Table where P.ITEMID == itemid && P.IMAGESIZE == size select P.PATH);
return o.Any() ? o.FirstOrDefault() : null;
```

I expect this to produce a SQL query with a where clause, but what it actually produces is this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ITEMID] AS [ITEMID], 
[Extent1].........
snap 10 columns
FROM [dbo].[TABLE] AS [Extent1]
```

The where clause and select (I try to select only one column) are executed after enumeration. What I want it to do is to produce a SQL query with the where clause and select only one column.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a heads up, o.Any() ? o.FirstOrDefault():null is redundant. o.FirstOrDefault() will return null if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: What is `Table` exactly?

Comment: I put the null there just for now, I'm actually returning something instead but didn't want to post it here, it doesn't influence the query anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating an `IEnumerable<string>` type of object, EF runs this query in the first line. Then `Any()` or `FirstOrDefault()` are executed in the memory set. 
If you want to "continue" writing linq statements and run the query in the end; just go with `IQueryable<T>`.

```
IQueryable<string> o = (from P in Table where P.ITEMID == itemid && P.IMAGESIZE == size select P.PATH);
return o.SingleOrDefault();
```

but as Ryan Bennett suggested, it is easier to use;

```
return Table.Where(p => p.ITEMID == itemid && P.IMAGESIZE == size).SingleOrDefault().PATH;
```

Comment: True about Any and FirstOrDefault, but the WHERE should have been executed on the database, not in memory.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. I never knew that IEnumerable worked that way. IQueryable seems to be usuable in many more situations. Is this where the lazyness of linq comes in?

Comment: In fact if you write your linq statements on a queryable object, EF works in a deferred execution way. But when you cast a queryable object to a "solid" type, like IEnumerable, it just executes the query. As a summary, EF defers execution until IQueryable object is cast to a "solid" type.

Answer (score 0):

```
return table.FirstOrDefault(P => P.ITEMID == itemid && P.IMAGESIZE == size);
```

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish. This will give you a where clause in your SQL and immediatly bring back the record or null.